# how to get value of checked with checkbox row in php?

Tags: php, forms

I am trying to get values of rows which are checked using checkbox. So when I submit the form I want values of selected rows but I am not able to figure it out how to get it. Can anybody help me or guide me?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
    // what should I write here to get value of hidden fields name and email which was selected     
}
?>  
<!doctype>
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

// performing select all /deselect all checkbox operation  

    <SCRIPT language="javascript">
      $(function(){

        // add multiple select / deselect functionality
        $("#selectall").click(function () {
              $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });

        // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
        // and viceversa
        $(".case").click(function(){

            if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
                $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
            } else {
                $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
            }

        });
    });
    </SCRIPT>

</head><body>
    <div class = 'middle' style = 'width : 700px;background-color:beige'>

// creating grid view   

    <form type="post" name ="contacts">
<span><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></span>
     <div class = 'middle row'>NAME</div>
     <div class = 'middle row'>E-MAIL</div>
     <div class='line'></div>
     <div class='line'></div>
<?php foreach($email as $e){
echo "<div>
   <span><input type='checkbox' class='case' name='case'/></span>
   <div class='row'>".$e['name']."
       <input name='cname[]' type='hidden' value =".$e['name']."></div>
   <div class='row'>".$e['email']."
       <input name='cemail[]' type='hidden' value =".$e['email']."></div>
   </div><div class='line'></div>";
}
echo"<input type='submit' name='invite' value='invite'>
         </form></div></body></html>";
   }?>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's not working? You need to give it a try and post your code. Eliminate all code from above that's not relevant to your specific question.

Comment: while submitting form I want only value of checked row.but I dn't know how to do it in php ?

Comment: I understand that, but SO isn't a free freelancer service. You need to do some study and try it yourself first, then ask specific questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After submitting the form, the value of a checked checkbox appears in the `$_POST` array like any other form fields. In your case, you have multiple checkboxes named `case`. None of those has a specific value assigned, so `$_POST['case']` will equal `on` if any checkbox is checked, so this won't help you at all.

Change the name of the checkbox to `case[]` and assign a unique value to each, and `$_POST['case']` will contain an array of the values of all *checked* checkboxes after submit. For instance, you could repeat the values of the hidden fields in the `value` attribute of your checkbox.

I wrote a small php script that should help you to understand, how checkboxes work with php. Just run it, play with the checkboxes and have a look at the `$_POST` array afterwards.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="0"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="2"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="3"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" value="4"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<pre><?php var_dump($_POST); ?></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to keep your hidden fields and don't want to repeat their values in the checkbox element, you can also use the array key of their arrays as checkbox value:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
foreach($email as $e) {
    echo "<div>
        <span><input type='checkbox' class='case' name='case[]' value='".$i."'/></span>
        <div class='row'>".$e['name']."
            <input name='cname['".$i."']' type='hidden' value =".$e['name']."></div>
        <div class='row'>".$e['email']."
            <input name='cemail['".$i."']' type='hidden' value =".$e['email']."></div>
        </div><div class='line'></div>";
    $i++;
}
```

Now, if `$_POST['case']`contains the values 2, 4 and 8 for instance, the emails you are looking for, are in `$_POST['cemail'][2]`, `$_POST['cemail'][4]` and `$_POST['cemail'][8]`. Same applies for `$_POST['cname']`, of course.

Comment: `<?php
  if(isset($_POST['invite'])){
   $case = $_POST['case'];
       echo "<pre>";
            foreach($case as $cs){
     echo $_POST['cname['.$cs.']']."<br>";
   }    
  }
 ?>`

Comment: hy bro i am getting error `Notice: Undefined index: cname[0]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's a mistake in an argument of `form` tag:

```
<form type="post"
```

This should read

```
<form method="post"
```

Then, since you store name and e-mail in the `input`s named `cname[]` and `cemail[]`, they will be passed respectively in `$_POST['cname']` and `$_POST['cemail']` variables. Note that you named them in a way they will be passed as arrays, so actually, `$_POST['cname']` is an array - it contains a key-value pair of `0` and the value attribute of the input control. So actually, your name and e-mail will be in  `$_POST['cname'][0]` and `$_POST['cemail'][0]` variables.

Please analyse and also read [Dealing with Forms section](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) of PHP manual.

Comment: yeah but my problem is how to verify whether it was selected or not ?

Comment: Oh I see now. Then you missed functionality of the controls. Hidden inputs are not selectable; they're like always selected and passed with their form. To be able to select some options you have to use `input` type `checkbox` (like you did with the one named `case`, but name each e.g. `person[0]`, `person[1]`, ... and then, when processing the form, compare it against another array where you store the persons IDs with their names, e-mails, etc.